# My character has stopped jumping in this pygame script, why?

Tags: python, pygame

That's all there really is to the question, in an earlier version the jump function was working but since adding a fixed border to the pygame window for the sprite it can no longer jump, here is the entire code, although most of it is irrelevant please take note of the variable names and meanings:

```
#Imports

import pygame
import sys
import math

#Pygame Initialisation

pygame.init()
windowWidth=500
windowHeight=500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("ScreenShove WIP")

#Movement Initialisation ((c) means constant)

x=250       #X Position
y=434       #Y Position
dx=0        #Perceived Change in X
dy=0        #Perceived Change in Y
width=40    #Character Width (c)
height=60   #Character Height (c)
ax=3        #X axis acceleration (c)
ay=20       #Y axis acceleration (c)
xprev=0     #Previous X Position
yprev=0     #Previous Y Position
isJump=False#Is the sprite performing a jump?
dylock=0    #Counts the number of frames dy has been 0 in a jump
border=5    #Border size (c)

run = True
while run:

pygame.time.delay(20) #50 ish fps
#Add 1 indentation for all the following lines
#Exit Check

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

#Get Keypresses

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

#Y Movement Decay

assumeddx=x-xprev   #Recalculates "dx" based on previous positions.
assumeddy=y-yprev   #Recalculates "dy" based on previous positions.
xprev=x             #Fixes "xprev" and "yprev" for the next frame.
yprev=y

if isJump == True:                                          #If the sprite is performing a jump:
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and y<windowHeight-height-border:   #If the "s" key is pressed:
        dy+=math.ceil(ay/2)                                 #Increase the change in Y by half the Y axis acceleration constant
    if assumeddy==0 or dy==0:                               #If the calculated or perceived change in Y is 0:
        if dylock>=2:                                       #If the change in Y is equal to 0 at least twice this jump:
            isJump=False                                    #Declare the sprite has finished performing a jump
            dylock=0                                        #Reset the counter
            dy=0                                            #Set the perceived change in Y to 0
        else:                                               #Otherwise:
            dylock+=1                                       #Increase the counter by 1
    dy+=1                                                   #Increase the perceived change in Y by 1.
else:                                                       #Otherwise:
    dy=0                                                    #Set the perceived chnage in Y to 0.

#X Movement Decay

if dx>0:                                                    #If the perceived change in X is positive:
    dx-=1                                                   #Reduce it by 1
if dx<0:                                                    #If the perceived change in X is negative:
    dx+=1                                                   #Increase it by 1

#User Movement Changes

if keys[pygame.K_a] and x>=dx+border and dx>-10:                #If the "a" key is pressed and the sprite is in a valid position and the change in X exceeds -10:
    dx-=ax                                                      #Reduce the change in X by the X axis acceleration constant
elif keys[pygame.K_d] and x<windowWidth-width-border and dx<10: #If the "d" key is pressed and the sprite is in a valid position and the change in X does not exceed 10:
    dx+=ax                                                      #Increase the change in X by the X axis acceleration constant
if keys[pygame.K_w]:                                            #If the "w" key is pressed:
    if y >= dy+border and isJump==False and jumplock==False:    #If the sprite is in a valid position, is not performing a jump already and the jump key isn't locked:
        dy-=ay                                                  #Decrease the change in Y by the Y axis acceleration constant
        isJump = True                                           #Declare the sprite is performing a jump.
    jumplock=True                                               #Lock the jump key.
else:                                                           #Otherwise:
    jumplock=False                                              #Unlock the jump key.

#Border Fix for Velocity

if dx<0:                                                        #If the change in X is positive
    if x>=-dx+border:                                           #If the sprite is in a valid position
        x+=dx                                                   #Increase the X position by the change in X
    else:                                                       #Otherwise:
        dx=0                                                    #Set the change in X to 0
        x=border                                                #Set the X position to the nearest valid X position
if dx>0:
    if x<=windowWidth-width-border:
        x+=dx
    else:
        dx=0
        x=windowWidth-width-border
if dy>0:
    if y<=windowHeight-height-border:
        y+=dy
    else:
        dy=0
        y=windowHeight-height-border

#Border Fix for Position

if x<0+border:
    x=border
if x>windowWidth-width-border:
    x=windowWidth-width-border
if y>windowHeight-height-border:
    y=windowHeight-height-border

#Debugging

print("P:",x,y)
print("V:",dx,dy)
print("Jumping:",str(isJump))
print("Jump Locked:",str(jumplock))

#Draw to Screen

win.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 200 ,0), (x,y,width,height))
pygame.display.update()

#No more indentations

#Exit

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

In addition to the code here is a home made debugging log from the period I try to initiate a jump:

```
P: 250 434
V: 0 0
Jumping: False
Jump Locked: False
P: 250 434
V: 0 -20
Jumping: True
Jump Locked: True
P: 250 434
V: 0 -19
Jumping: True
Jump Locked: True
P: 250 434
V: 0 -18
Jumping: True
Jump Locked: False
P: 250 435
V: 0 1
Jumping: False
Jump Locked: False
P: 250 435
V: 0 0
Jumping: False
Jump Locked: False
```

P means position.

V means velocity or change in position.

Both are given as "X Y".

Jumping is the boolean "isJump" and
Jump Locked is the boolean "jumplock".

Comment: Just as an aside, this is the point at which in developing some code you really strongly benefit from better structuring. If adding in or removing code starts causing bugs it's a pretty good hint that the structure needs improving.

Comment: I would assume that it's because this line evaluates to false. Does your debugger give you any hints? `if keys[pygame.K_s] and y<windowHeight-height-border:`

Comment: Actually, that did nothing :( I think its got something to do with the Border Fix for Position or Velocity sections.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
if dy>0:
    if y<=windowHeight-height-border:
        y+=dy
    else:
        dy=0
        y=windowHeight-height-border
```

I should have done this:

```
if y<=windowHeight-height-border:
    y+=dy
elif dy>0:
    dy=0
    y=windowHeight-height-border
```

Because dy is not always a positive value (well no way Tom).

Turns out it was to do with me removing the upper limit of the window so jumps aren't capped at the window ceiling.